# how to extend a set to an R-basis of V4(R)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm going through some questions in my book and there's one in particular that I can't really find explanations on. Any help would be really appreciated (with worked solutions if possible as I don't understand the topic of vector spaces completely). Thanks in advance!

The question:
Extend $\{(1,2,4,0),(1,0,0,5)\}$ to an $R$-basis of $V_4(R)$.

Comment: By "V4(R)", do you mean $\mathbb{R}^4$ or something else?

Comment: yes i mean exactly that, sorry

Comment: to speak roughly, crudely, and inaccurately, if you add any old two random $4$-vectors to the set, you’ll have a basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we observe the following:

> $\textbf{Theorem:}$ Let $V$ be a vector space
>   that is generated by a set $G$ containing exactly $n$ vectors, and let $L$ be a
>   linearly independent subset of $V$ containing exactly $m$ vectors. Then $m \leq n$ and there exists a subset H of G containing exactly $n — m$ vectors such that $L \cup H $ generates V.
>
> $\textbf{Corollary:}$  Let $V$ be a vector space with dimension n.
>
> (a) Any finite generating set for V contains at least n vectors, and a generating
>   set for V that contains exactly n vectors is a basis for V.
>
> (b) Any linearly independent subset of V that contains exactly n vectors is
>   a basis for V.
>
> (c) $\textbf{Every linearly independent subset of V can be extended to a basis for
> V}$

So first check whether your two vectors is linearly independent or not.

Fix any basis S for $\mathbb{R}^4$.

One method is adding two vectors from S  to your list and check if the 4 vectors are linearly independent, if not, then choose another two vectors until you have the 4 linearly independent vectors.

The second thing is fix any basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$ and combine these four to your two vectors. Now we eliminate the dependent vectors.

Comment: thank you so much! the clearest explanation I could have ever asked for.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to extend the set with the standard basis and then reduce it to a basis, e.g. by row reducing the matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$
and then selecting all the column vectors in the matrix above corresponding to pivot columns in the row reduced matrix.